# How can you show that 2 (adjacency) matrices are isomorphic?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, group-isomorphism, graph-isomorphism

Would you do it by showing that elementary matrix operations can be used to get from one matrix to the other? If not, how would you show that 2 adjacency matrices are isomorphic?

Answer (score 1):

Adjacency matrices $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic graphs iff there exists a [permutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix) $S$ such that $A = SBS^{-1}$.
This doesn't necessarily help you decide if the two *are* isomorphic, since you still would have to check all $n!$ permutations. However, it gives lots of easy ways to detect when $A$ and $B$ are *not* isomorphic, because this implies that they are similar by a unitary matrix. For example:

- If $\det A \ne \det B$ then they are not isomorphic.
- If $\text{Tr } A^m \ne \text{Tr } B^m$ then they are not isomorphic.
- Any other property that depends only on $A, B$ being linear maps on an inner product space of dimension $n$, and not on the specific orthonormal basis chosen.

---

Computationally speaking, deciding when two adjacency matrix are isomorphic is equivalent to showing two graphs are isomorphic, and is a [famous problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem) since it is not known to be either in $P$ or be $NP$-complete. However, there is currently a [potential breakthrough](https://lucatrevisan.wordpress.com/2015/11/03/laci-babai-and-graph-isomorphism/) showing that it can be solved in "quasipolynomial time", that is to say, in time equal to $2^{P(\log n)}$ where $P$ is a polynomial.

Comment: Adjacency matrices of graphs have diagonal elements $0$, and therefore trace $0$.  But you could consider $\text{Tr}\; A^m$ and $\text{Tr}\; B^m$ for positive integer $m$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Good point.